# \n Does not work in html5-canvas ctx.fillText()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, newline, whitespace, line-breaks

```
ctx.fillText("Hello\nWorld", 300, 300);
```

This is supposed to show `World` below `Hello` but when used it is being displayed as `Hello World`

How do I make it work correctly?